# aws-sdk for Ruby v2: check success status after I PUT object in S3 bucket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-sdk

I'm using the aws-sdk v2 for Ruby and I find the methods available on objects really limiting. I created a bucket like so:

```
client = Aws::S3::Client.new(region: 'us-west-2')
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(client: client)
S3_BUCKET = s3.bucket(ENV['AWS_BUCKET'])
```

I've found that the only methods available to write an object to my bucket is `put.` However, I don't see a 'success_action_status' available with this method. I've deployed my app to Elastic Beanstalk. Locally, I can write to this bucket, but when I try and write to my eb app, it's not working and I am working blind trying to figure out what's happening. Any info to help determine where my PUT request is going wrong would be helpful.

Here's what my method looks like now:

```
  def create
    username = params[:user][:user_alias]
    key = "uploads/#{username}"
    obj = S3_BUCKET.object(key)

    obj.put({
      acl: 'public-read',
      body: params[:user][:image_uri],
    })

    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user
    else
      render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

Here's the documentation I'm referring to for PUT methods: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Object.html#put-instance_method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem like you're `put`ing the image file, only the uri. The docs say this about the `put` method's `body` option:

```
body: source_file, # file/IO object, or string data
```

You'll have to read or open the image file in order to actually upload the image:

```
obj.put({
  acl: 'public-read',
  body: File.open(params[:user][:image_uri], ?r),
})
```

Then you can check the success status with [exists?](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Object.html#exists%3F-instance_method)

Comment: That makes sense, thank you! The image will be set as a bytea datatype - do I still need to read / open in order for it to get uploaded?

Comment: Also, I'm confused about why something does get posted to S3 locally but nothing appears on the deployed app. Right now I'm testing by passing in a string and the string appears in the S3 bucket when I post locally, but when I perform the exact same post on eb nothing appears. Why would it not work on the deployed version?

Comment: Does your server have the AWS creds or a policy that let's it write to S3?

Comment: I didn't actively set those up, so probably not. I have been poking around in documentation but am unclear how to give my Elastic Beanstalk application a policy to write to S3.

Comment: You'll have to log into your AWS console, go to the EC2 section, there should be an instance for your app there and options to add policies to it http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-policies-for-amazon-ec2.html